# Closure of set of rational numbers whose decimal representation does not contain the digit 7

Tags: general-topology

What is the closure of set of rational numbers whose decimal representation does not contain the digit $7$? I stumbled upon a question which asked to prove that the above set is not dense in $\mathbb{R}$. This was not difficult, and similarly it is not difficult to show that it is not even dense in $\mathbb{Q}$, but it made me wonder, what would the closure of this set look like?

Comment: To be clear, is the element $0.7$ in your set?  Is the element $0.6999999999\cdots$ in your set?  It sounds like you are trying to describe a [Cantor-like set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_set) but it is unclear the exact definition.  Next, when you say closure do you mean the smallest parent set that is closed which contains this set?  [Cantor-like sets are often closed](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2899523/confusion-with-the-proof-that-the-cantor-set-is-closed) already.  Or, might you be thinking instead of the *completion* of the set?

Comment: You might investigate the well-known Cantor Set, which, depending on how the endpoints are treated, is formed by excluding numbers which contain a $1$ in their base $3$ expansion (your example excludes $7$ in base $10$)

Comment: Numbers with a *single* $7$ in their (standard) decimal representation would be in the closure (a la $0.69999\ldots = 0.7$) whereas those with two or more $7$'s are not

Comment: @JMoravitz I would have thought $0.7$ was in the closure of the set in $\mathbb R$ in either case, since $0.7$ is not in the interior of its complement, though I may be wrong

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Would $0.72 = 0.719999\ldots$ be in the closure?

Comment: My question was not whether $0.7$ is in the closure of the set... it should be obvious that it is.  The question was whether $0.7$ is in the original set itself since $0.7$ "*has no 7's in (one of) its decimal representation(s).*"  The distinction is, as MarkBennet alludes to, whether the endpoints were included or excluded from the intervals in question during the construction of the set.  As for $0.72$ is in the set or its closure, obviously not since no numbers in the range $(0.7,0.8)$ are in the set.

Comment: @JMoravitz to be clear, closure indeed means the smallest closed set that contains our set. Now, about 0.6999999, I really didn't think about if it should be included in the set, so which choice would you consider the most rigorous? Because it seems like it both should and should not be included